# Malware transmitted over network

Tags: firewall, malware, windows-firewall

I am doing some tests in my second computer which involve dropping the firewall and antivirus.

I'm trying to isolate the 2 systems so malware can't jump between them.

Both systems have win8 installed and I'm using wireless connection, ipv4 to connect to the internet.

Comment: Yes, of course it can. What is your specific question?

Comment: @slhck basically if there's a way to isolate the 2 computers so nothing can go between them but both have internet access

Comment: That depends on your router's capabilities. If they're both in the same network (virtual or phyical), the computers can reach each other, unless the router blocks these connections, or you can set up virtual networks that separate these two. Can you maybe [edit] your question and rewrite it to state your actual problem? Include specifics as to what operating systems are involved, what your router is, your IP setup, et cetera. Thanks